# Запуск программы без ожидания поступления данных

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt

Подскажите, как сделать так, чтобы программа сразу запускалась, а не ждала пока загрузятся данные с сайта?
        мне нужно что бы сначала отобразилась зта надпись 
"загрузка данных..."
а потом заголовок страницы ................
кто может перепешите код заранее спасибо!
Вот код:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QWidget, QPushButton, QLabel,QInputDialog,  QApplication)
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon,QFont,QColor,QPalette,QPixmap,QBrush
from PyQt5 import QtCore
from  urllib.request import urlopen 
from lxml import html
import threading


class Пример(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()
    def initUI(self):
        self.setGeometry(10, 30, 250, 200)
        self.setWindowTitle('PyQt5')
        self.label = QLabel(self)
        self.label.setText(str("загрузка данных..."))
        self.label.setGeometry(0,0,188,20)
        self.label2=QLabel(self)
        self.label2.setGeometry(0,0,188,20)

        if p2.is_alive()!=False:
            self.label.hide()
            self.label2.setText(str(proc2()))
            self.label2.show()


def proc():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    пример=Пример()
    пример.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

def proc2():
    страница=urlopen('http://gismeteo.ru/weather-rudniy-4629').read()
    parsed_body=html.fromstring(страница)
    заголовок=parsed_body.xpath('//title/text()')[0]
    return заголовок
p1=threading.Thread(target=proc)
p2=threading.Thread(target=proc2)
p1.start()
p2.start()

p1.join()
p2.join()
```

Comment: Используйте `threading.Thread` или `QNetworkAccessManager`. Второе будет даже предпочтительней, так как вы испольузете Qt.

Comment: Я начинающий . можете написать подробнее про QNetworkAccessManager ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вариант с `QNetworkAcessManager`. При такой реализации, сначала запускается ваше приложение, потом спустя 500мс отправляется сигнал на загрузку данных. После того как данные будут загружены будет вызван метод `loaded` в котором произойдет обработка данных и их отображение.

```
import sys

from PyQt5 import Qt
from lxml import html


class Weather(Qt.QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.nam = Qt.QNetworkAccessManager()
        self.initUI()
        Qt.QTimer.singleShot(500, self.on_timer)

    def initUI(self):
        self.setGeometry(10, 30, 250, 200)
        self.setWindowTitle('PyQt5')
        layout = Qt.QVBoxLayout(self)

        self.label = Qt.QLabel("Загрузка данных...")
        self.label.setGeometry(0, 0, 188, 20)
        self.label2 = Qt.QLabel()
        self.label2.setGeometry(0, 0, 188, 20)

        layout.addWidget(self.label)
        layout.addWidget(self.label2)

    def loaded(self):
        self.label.setText("Данные загружены!")
        page = self.reply.readAll().data().decode()
        parsed_body = html.fromstring(page)
        self.label2.setText(parsed_body.xpath('//title/text()')[0])

    def on_error(self):
        Qt.QMessageBox.critical(self, 'Error', self.reply.errorString())

    def on_timer(self):
        url = Qt.QUrl('https://gismeteo.ru/weather-rudniy-4629')
        self.nr = Qt.QNetworkRequest(url)
        self.reply = self.nam.get(self.nr)
        self.reply.finished.connect(self.loaded)
        self.reply.error.connect(self.on_error)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = Qt.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Weather()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

P.S. Не пишите код на русском языке, привыкайте сразу использовать только английский язык.